# Избежать повторного объявления функции

Tags: php

Есть модуль, вызываемый на странице дважды (отображение в MVC), а внутри него - функция, генерирующая часть разметки. Framework, который я использую в работе, кеширует некоторые файлы, и при кешировании объявление этой функции вызывается второй раз (так как отображение выводится на странице дважды).

Как с такой проблемой принято бороться? Выносить функции в отдельный файл, подключая его через `use`, создавать дополнительное отображение вместо функции, генерирующей разметку или, возможно, другими способами?

Comment: От фреймворка зависит. Как ваш называется?

Comment: Может можно использовать грубый хак: `if (!function_exists('имя_функции')){}`

Comment: @Sergey Rufanov, Laravel.

Comment: @cyadvert, ваш вариант помог, спасибо.

Comment: Вам стоит разделить оъявление функционала и его использование. Вывод не должен подгружать новый функционал (и, в идеале, не иметь такой возможности).